# Product of a known prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Lets say we have a set of numbers `k = [44, 3, 17, 10, 64]` and a known prime number `p=11`. How do I filter all the numbers from this list which can be decomposed as `p * x`, where `x` is some natural number *strictly greater than* a positive number `n`? For example, in the above list `k`, if we set `n=2`, we can filter `44` out, as it fulfills the criteria of this decomposition (`44 = p * 4`).

One way I can think of is to divide every element in `k` by `p`, and pick all the ones which are wholly divided. But not sure how to fulfill the constraint for `n`. Is there a way around it? Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just divide $k$ by $p$ and see if the result is a whole number *and* greater than $n$? (Or reverse the process and check that $k > pn$ first?) Primality of $p$ seems completely irrelevant too - you're just checking divisibility and a lower bound after all.

Comment: "we can filter 33"...May be 33 is to be replaced with 44.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract $np$ from the entire set. Discard those that are not positive. Divide the remaining by $p$ to see which ones are multiples of $p$.